# Extract text between 2 strings from word document using aspose.words in C#

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I have a word document from which I need to extract a few lines of text. the text i need to extract can be found in between the two strings: “must haves” and “could haves”. Does anyone know what I should do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IReplacingCallback](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.replacing/ireplacingcallback) to achieve what you need. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\temp\in.docx");
FindReplaceOptions opt = new FindReplaceOptions();
opt.ReplacingCallback = new MyReplacingCallback();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<mytag\>(.*?)\<\/mytag\>");
doc.Range.Replace(regex, "", opt);
```

```cs
private class MyReplacingCallback : IReplacingCallback
{
    public ReplaceAction Replacing(ReplacingArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Match.Groups[1].Value);
        return ReplaceAction.Skip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use tika to extract text from docx...  :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TikaOnDotNet.TextExtractor

```
var str = new TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractor().Extract(@"C:\Users\Inconnu\Downloads\test.docx").Text;

            int pForm = str.IndexOf("must haves") + "must haves".Length;
            int pTo = str.LastIndexOf("could haves");

            string result = str.Substring(pForm, pTo - pForm);
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error on the first line: MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)'.